# Embedding CordovaWebview in Ionic Project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordovawebview

After going through Ionic test dummy to do app, I am creating my first App using the tabs template. I would like to embed a WebView instead of the dashboard page template. I have read the instructions at  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews1 severally but I do not get it, or rather, I am not finding the files they want me to get.

I installed everything via CLI anf my cordova directory is at `C:\Users\<Username>\.cordova` and the file structure follows as `\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\framework` in here there are directories like `.settings` ,`assets` , `res` etc.

Someone please help how to go about adding a website link to load the webView.

Comment: if you created the ionic app using ionic CLI, then it already includes cordova webview

Comment: How then do I initiate a web view to show in my index page?